# Deploying code on render.com with docker as a runtime throwing error on mvn clean package command

Tags: spring-boot, docker, deployment, dockerfile, render.com

I deployed my backend code on render with docker as a runtime

This is my Dockerfile

```
#
# Build stage
#
# Use the official maven/Java 8 image to create a build artifact.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/maven
FROM maven:3.8.2-jdk-11 as build
#
# # Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .
#
# # Build a release artifact.
RUN mvn clean package


#
# Package stage
#
# It's important to use OpenJDK 8u191 or above that has container support enabled.
# https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim

# Copy the jar to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=build /target/Hostel-Availability-System-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Hostel-Availability-System.jar

# ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the web service on container startup.
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Hostel-Availability-System.jar"]
```

This is the error message

```
 [build 3/3] RUN mvn clean install:
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [INFO] Total time:  18.592 s
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-24T15:08:02Z
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project Hostel-Availability-System: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [ERROR]
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [ERROR]
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  #11 21.15 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  ------
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  Dockerfile:12
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  --------------------
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM    10 |     #
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM    11 |     # # Build a release artifact.
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM    12 | >>> RUN mvn clean install
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM    13 |
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM    14 |
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  --------------------
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mvn clean install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Apr 24 08:38:02 PM  error: exit status 1
```

Full Error Logs - https://pastebin.com/y23cm1dT

Git Repo Link - https://github.com/harmanmalhotra/HAS-Backend

Anyone knows how to solve this issue. I am stuck on it for a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Docker images with Java 11 installed for building your image:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11 as builder
...

FROM openjdk:11-slim as runtime
...
```

As the error message states, Java 17 is expected:

```
invalid target release: 17
```

Change your Docker images to Java 17 images and it will work:

- [maven](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) for building: e.g. [`maven:3.8-openjdk-17`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.8-openjdk-17/images/sha256-62e6a9e10fb57f3019adeea481339c999930e7363f2468d1f51a7c0be4bca26d?context=explore)
- for runtime e.g. [`ibm-semeru-runtimes:open-17-jre-centos7`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ibm-semeru-runtimes/open-17-jre-centos7/images/sha256-25e8305a19ea47480afed94c11945a878e665a7cf9f8218a5786bab2c7163501?context=explore)

There are many more available, do your own research on what might be best suited for you. The above mentioned are the ones I use.